# How to disable middleware for certain functions using a decorator?

Tags: python, django

I would like to mimic the behavior of `csrf_exempt`(see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt) and [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/middleware/csrf.py#L208)). The problem with following the CSRF middleware way of doing it is that it uses `from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin`, which is deprecated. Is there a way I can do this using the [recommended way](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware) of creating middleware in Django 1.11? I am also aware of `from django.utils.decorators import decorator_from_middleware` but that's the opposite of what I want. Anybody have any ideas?

Edit: The following works but is not the prettiest, recommendations?

```
class MyMiddleware(object):
    def __init(self, get_response):
        # initialization

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        if getattr(view_func, "my_middleware_exempt", False):
            request.exempt = True
            return None

        # Perform request logic

    def __call__(self, request):
        # __call__ has to be included, even though I don't want it.
        response = self.get_response(request)
        # If I wanted to perform logic after the request,
        # I would have to check the flag I set on the request
        # in process_view
        if not request.exempt:
            # perform logic
        return response

def exempt_decorator(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    decorator.my_middleware_exempt = True
    return decorator
```

Comment: `MiddlewareMixin` is not deprecated... it's a tool to convert deprecated middleware, but it'll be a while before it will be deprecated (if ever). Either way, `process_view` still works the same way, and you can just use the same code in new-style middleware.

Comment: Then why does [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/middleware/#upgrading-pre-django-1-10-style-middleware) exist, what class do you have to include to get the hook `process_view`?

Comment: You just define the `process_view` method on your middleware class. You don't need to subclass any class. That hasn't changed in 1.11 with the new-style middleware.

Comment: In order to get the view_func parameter I'm pretty sure you have to subclass something. It didn't work with just object.

Comment: `process_view` only requires that it is a valid middleware. `MiddlewareMixin` can be used to create a valid middleware class, but it's not required. Please show what you have tried and what error you get. You're using the new `MIDDLEWARE` setting, right?